# Audio being played from microphone is choppy and sounds like air blowing into the microphone

Tags: ios, swift, audio, type-conversion, avaudioplayer

I'm recording audio using the following:

```
    localInput?.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 4096, format: localInputFormat) {
        (buffer, time) -> Void in

        let audioBuffer = self.audioBufferToBytes(audioBuffer: buffer)
        let output = self.outputStream!.write(audioBuffer, maxLength: Int(buffer.frameLength))

        if output > 0 {
            print("\(#file) > \(#function) > \(output) bytes written from queue \(self.currentQueueName())")
        }
        else if output == -1 {
            let error = self.outputStream!.streamError
            print("\(#file) > \(#function) > Error writing to stream: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

Where my localInputFormat is the following:

```
self.localInput = self.localAudioEngine.inputNode
self.localAudioEngine.attach(self.localAudioPlayer)
self.localInputFormat = self.localInput?.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
self.localAudioEngine.connect(self.localAudioPlayer, to: self.localAudioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: self.localInputFormat)
```

The function audioBufferToBytes is as follows:

```
func audioBufferToBytes(audioBuffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer) -> [UInt8] {
    let srcLeft = audioBuffer.floatChannelData![0]
    let bytesPerFrame = audioBuffer.format.streamDescription.pointee.mBytesPerFrame
    let numBytes = Int(bytesPerFrame * audioBuffer.frameLength)

    // initialize bytes by 0 
    var audioByteArray = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: numBytes)

    srcLeft.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: numBytes) { srcByteData in
        audioByteArray.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {
            $0.baseAddress!.initialize(from: srcByteData, count: numBytes)
        }
    }

    return audioByteArray
}
```

On the other device, when I receive the data I have to convert it back. So as it's received it runs through the following:

```
func bytesToAudioBuffer(_ buf: [UInt8]) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer {

    let fmt = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 1, interleaved: true)
    let frameLength = UInt32(buf.count) / fmt.streamDescription.pointee.mBytesPerFrame

    let audioBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: fmt, frameCapacity: frameLength)
    audioBuffer.frameLength = frameLength

    let dstLeft = audioBuffer.floatChannelData![0]

    buf.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
        let src = UnsafeRawPointer($0.baseAddress!).bindMemory(to: Float.self, capacity: Int(frameLength))
        dstLeft.initialize(from: src, count: Int(frameLength))
    }

    return audioBuffer
}
```

And lastly, we play this audio data:

```
                self.audioPlayerQueue.async {
                    self.peerAudioPlayer.scheduleBuffer(audioBuffer)

                    if (!self.peerAudioPlayer.isPlaying && self.localAudioEngine.isRunning) {
                        self.peerAudioPlayer.play()
                    }
                }
```

However, on either speaker I just hear what sounds like someone tapping the microphone every half-second(ish). Not them actually talking or anything. I imagine this is due to my conversion from an audio buffer to bytes and back, but I'm not sure. Does anyone see any issues with the above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested in the solution, basically the issue was that the audio on the recording device was 17640 bytes but to stream it, it breaks it up into smaller pieces, and on the receiving device I had to read the first 17640 bytes and THEN play the audio. Not play every small bit of data that was received.